# Displaying multiple document data in ListView in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, stream-builder

Here is the code that im using. What im trying to achieve is to display different drivers from each container in the ListView found inside the RadioItem. Currently it just displays one name on repeat as seen in the Photo attached.[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcsuY.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class BeepListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BeepListViewState createState() => _BeepListViewState();
}

class _BeepListViewState extends State<BeepListView> {
  List<RadioModel> beepUnits = new List<RadioModel>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 1'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 2'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 3'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 4'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 5'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 6'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 7'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 8'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 9'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 10'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 11'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 12'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 13'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 14'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 15'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 16'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 17'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 18'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 19'));
    beepUnits.add(new RadioModel(false, 'Unit 20'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double defaultScreenWidth = 400.0;
    double defaultScreenHeight = 810.0;

    ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil(
      width: defaultScreenWidth,
      height: defaultScreenHeight,
      allowFontScaling: true,
    )..init(context);
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      height: 100.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: beepUnits.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.blue,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                beepUnits.forEach((element) => element.isSelected = false);
                beepUnits[index].isSelected = true;
              });
            },
            child: new RadioItem(beepUnits[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RadioItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final RadioModel _item;
  RadioItem(this._item);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('driver')
            .where('status', isEqualTo: 'On Duty')
            .limit(1)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return new Text(' ');
            default:
              return Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      height: 100.0,
                      width: 160.0,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                              child: new Text(
                                'ETA',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: _item.isSelected
                                      ? Colors.grey[200]
                                      : Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: ScreenUtil.instance.setSp(29.0),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.directions_bus,
                                          color: _item.isSelected
                                              ? Colors.grey[200]
                                              : Colors.black,
                                          size: ScreenUtil.instance.setSp(19.0),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        child: new Text(
                                          _item.buttonTitle,
                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                            color: _item.isSelected
                                                ? Colors.grey[200]
                                                : Colors.black,
                                            fontSize:
                                                ScreenUtil.instance.setSp(15.0),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.swap_calls,
                                          color: _item.isSelected
                                              ? Colors.grey[200]
                                              : Colors.black,
                                          size: ScreenUtil.instance.setSp(19.0),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        child: new Text(
                                          'Distance',
                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                            color: _item.isSelected
                                                ? Colors.grey[200]
                                                : Colors.black,
                                            fontSize:
                                                ScreenUtil.instance.setSp(15.0),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.face,
                                          color: _item.isSelected
                                              ? Colors.grey[200]
                                              : Colors.black,
                                          size: ScreenUtil.instance.setSp(19.0),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        children: snapshot.data.documents
                                            .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                          return Container(
                                            child: new Text(
                                              '${document['fname']}',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                color: _item.isSelected
                                                    ? Colors.grey[200]
                                                    : Colors.black,
                                                fontSize: ScreenUtil.instance
                                                    .setSp(15.0),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color:
                            _item.isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
                        border: new Border.all(
                          width: 0.5,
                          color: _item.isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
          }
        });
  }
}

class RadioModel {
  bool isSelected;
  final String buttonTitle;

  RadioModel(this.isSelected, this.buttonTitle);
}
```

i have tried removing the limit but all it does is display all the names in one container and will still go on repeat and display the same names from all the containers

Comment: I think the problem is with your query, you request each time same one:

Firestore.instance
            .collection('driver')
            .where('status', isEqualTo: 'On Duty')
            .limit(1)
            .snapshots()

Could you remove your limit and try again?

Comment: I have tried removing the limit already and all it did was display all the names in one container

Comment: It's okay, just switch your ListView.builder and StreamBuilder,
StreamBuilder should be as your top widget, and as you get one element from stream, you can create elements for your ListView.builder

Comment: we actually got the code on how to do it, we just added an initState() and placed the Firestore.instance inside of it. Thanks tho! I appreciate the help :)